# Would you go public with corruption?

Tags: legal-issues, whistleblowing

What if there is a hypothetical situation where someone witnessed an enormous amount of corruption in their department/institution; let us say that it is not simply a whiny graduate student, but a number of legalities were involved and violated.  This person exhausted all possible avenues at the institution.  I will also propose that this person is not interested in maintaining any ties with academia.  This person is already working on a career outside of academia.  This person is also not interested in a lawsuit.

Many hypothetical friends of the described person think the individual should go public with their story (i.e. facts).  It isn't libel if it is true and that truth could be supported by evidence.

Would you go public, and why?
How would one protect themselves from further retaliation?

Comment: https://wikileaks.org/

Comment: Yes, wikileaks is well known.  But are you saying you would go public, or not?

Comment: That hypothetical person shouldn't go public on their own. They should find someone who already has experience with exposing academic corruption and go public through them, because it increases the likelihood that something will change - simply because going public that way will get more media exposure.

Comment: if one could do it anonymously, what reason would there be not to?

Comment: What sort of entities/persons have experience with exposing academic corruption besides lawyers?

Comment: "All that is necessary for the triumph of evil is that good men do nothing." Hypothetical good men.

Comment: Evil and good are _very_ subjective terms. And the OP is in a dire need of an edit, as all those hypotheticals really muddle the question.

Comment: Hypothetically, you shouldn't ask questions that promote discussion or rely on personal viewpoints or  aren't focused on a single issue, on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Asking if you would go public with corruption is a single issue.  Most answers on SE are personal viewpoints (i.e. how to deal with manuscripts, advisers, degrees, applications, teaching, etc.).  Instead of promoting a discussion, you could have answered the question.

Comment: You've asked about at least two issues: would an individual go public with reason, and, how to protect from backlash. These are things that can **only** be determined personally for anybody, your first question is the archetype of those which receive primarily-opinion-based answers. And "most answers on SE are personal viewpoints" is a caricature of the common practise and professional experience presented on Academia SE, let alone the rest of Stack Exchange.

Comment: See the [help/dont-ask] about what kinds of questions _not_ to ask. If you give further details about the situation that narrow the scope of the question significantly, it may be reopened. (In particular, note that the question of whether to go public, and what might be gained by going public, depend in large part on the specifics of the situation.) See other questions tagged [tag:whistleblowing] for examples.

Comment: "Yes, wikileaks is well known. But are you saying you would go public, or not?" Your question would imply that you're interested in getting credit for the whistleblowing. In my opinion, there is practically no upside for taking credit unless you want to become a journalist (or unless there is a financial incentive as part of a whistleblowing program). Just imagine how a potential employer would react if he googled your name and found out that you had been a whistleblower. Is being a former whistleblower really a positive attribute for many employers? I don't think so.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure you should just dump your info somewhere on some websites for leaks. If I were you, I would look for a journalist(s) that has had a good track record of going after the institution you want to go after.

Comment: I had another reason to vote to close this question "unclear what you're asking" _an enormous amount of corruption_ what kind of corruption are we talking about here? This reason still exists. Vote to remain closed.

Comment: Hypothetically, what if there is a situation where someone has completely blown perceived issues out of all proportion?

Comment: I also want to second @Nij's comment, and his statement that `_ "most answers on SE are personal viewpoints" is a caricature of the common practise and professional experience presented on Academia SE, let alone the rest of Stack Exchange._' This may have been the case on the only other question you have asked to date, but there are numerous examples on academia.SE let alone math.SE, TeX.SE etc which go against your assessment

Comment: @Yemon Choi.  Your attitude is persistent across academia.  Without knowing the specifics of this case (I have withheld them for a reason), your comment is silly.  Hypothetically, the misconduct took place on a multi-million dollar grant.  Hypothetically, the feds are already involved.  Hypothetically, this person won't have to go public, as others may do it for them.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry that you find my attitude persistent across academia (don't you mean "prevalent across", or "persistent within"?) but I am calling it as I see it. Frankly, the phrasing of your question is disingenuous. Given that you clearly feel wronged, whether on your behalf or on someone else's, this feels more like an attempt to canvas support than an attempt to seek information

Comment: Moreover (and it seems that your first question on academia.SE may have set an unfortunate precedent) I do not think this site is suited to questions which just ask "guys, what would you do in this situation?" This is not a forum for discussion, nor is it a blog. If you have a specific question about procedures or legal recourse then that is another matter. If you just want to rail against the slings and arrows of outrageous fortune, other venues might be more appropriate

Comment: @ Yemon Choi.  Yes, let us argue over adverbs over the internet.  Your comments are a microcosm example of how academicians obsess over non-issues when faced with serious issues. No, your assumptions about my question are poorly based.  My question is genuine.  It was merely an attempt to gauge the value of going public with facts concerning corruption in academia.

Comment: Why you are using my first question on SE as a basis for a mild complaint is beyond me.  I received many positive responses to my first question on SE. In fact, for what it is worth, I earned a number of points for that question.  Why are the quibbles in academe so intense?  Because the stakes are so low.  This is true unless someone brings law into the question.  Should I have presented my question in the "Law" section?  That said, please review the nature of most questions under the "Academia" section of SE.  Most questions are far more trivial than this one.

Comment: @Yemon Choi.  You should be thankful you didn't do something as professionally stupid as others have.  Otherwise, you may have been one among the featured individuals of this question.  I would imagine if you did engage in scientific/professional misconduct, you would rather it never be known to the public.

Comment: Corruption and malpractice in academia are important issues, and I am willing to believe -- given things that have come to light over the last deacde or two -- that it is a serious problem. Nevertheless, this is not the site for **discussing** this! Your question was explicitly inviting a lot of suggestions, and I feel the signal-noise ratio is low on this kind of question, **as evidenced by your first question** (which is why I keep bringing it up). If you started an anonymous blog where you wanted to vent or discuss I would be happy to enter into dialogue. **This is not a blog**

Comment: Moreover, regardless of my pedantry, I don't think this question was closed because "academicians obsess over non-issues when faced with serious issues." If a serious issue of corruption/malpractice was brought to me or many of my colleagues we'd take it seriously. But since you are understandably omitting details, I'm not in that position, where specific+relevant suggestions could be made; I'm in a position where someone unknown tells me "bad things happened, what does one do". You're asking whether a course of action is "right" or "advisable"; I'm saying it depends on the particular details.

Answer (score 2):

In making the decision on whether to blow the whistle one may want to consider [past cases](http://www.whistleblowers.org.au/whistleblowersstories.html) of whistle blowing and learn from these.

Whether one chooses to do his is ultimately a personal choice but a whistle blower would probably want to do some research into past successful (and unsuccessful) attempts.

If one can find a past example of successful whistle-blowing in a similar field then these methods can provide a starting point. There are now anonymous submission systems such as [globaleaks](https://www.globaleaks.org/) and [securedrop](https://securedrop.org/) which offer a certain level of anonymity. However you should regard these with caution:

> **"** Other submission technologies inspired by WikiLeaks, such as the
>   European-based GlobaLeaks and the US-based Secure Drop, while both
>   excellent in many ways, are not suited to WikiLeaks’ sourcing in its
>   national security and large archive publishing specialities. **"**

--[Wikileaks](https://wikileaks.org/Some-notes-on-the-new-WikiLeaks.html)

Since this hypothetical situation relates to [academia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Academic_scandals), the stakes are unlikely to be as high as those faced by [Edward Snowden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Snowden) and [Chelsea Manning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chelsea_Manning). (Although they could be for someone exposing something like MKULTRA)

There are journalists that use these [technologies](http://leakdirectory.org/index.php/Leak_Site_Directory) to receive tips, one would also want to establish the trustworthiness of these. (Ask: Have they successfully published in the past?)

Whistleblowers don't necessarily use these systems though, in the case of the [nauru files](https://www.theguardian.com/news/series/nauru-files) it appears that the journalists worked with a whistleblower.

Ask: Is there a suitable organisation interesting in taking this up? (One with no ties to the guilty party) If something illegal has occurred, police may be interested in addressing this once tipped off. Thus mitigating the whistle-blower's risk.

> How would one protect themselves from further retaliation?

Anonymity appears to be an effective method if it can be maintained. (I don't recommend identifying yourself with this stack exchange account.)

One would also need to assess the potential risk. (How powerful is my adversary?)

Ask: Can the whistle-blower change allegiances if found out? How easy this is will  depend on specific situations, Edward Snowden needed to move country. Someone in academia may only need to change university.

If litigation is a concern, anonymity is probably best.

Comment: Some institutions that handle whistleblowing demand the whistleblower provide their name. To me, this appears to be a big red flag. I would not provide any personally identifiable information.

Comment: “Courage is not the absence of fear. Only fools have no fear. 
Rather, courage is the intellectual mastery of fear by understanding 
the true risks and opportunities of the situation and keeping those 
things in balance” -- Julian Assange

Comment: Nice words.  Hypothetically, would it be better to write a book, use one of the whistleblower avenue sources you referenced, or both?

Comment: In principle you shouldn't be, but in practice I'd be wary of using my institution's network to research whistle-blowing.

Comment: @M11293 It depends on your situation. Writing a book sounds like it would rule out anonymity. But this is ok if you have already been found out. Peter Wright, wrote spycatcher and it became so popular the British government could not even bar him receiving royalties. William McNeilly disclosed his identity to give his claims credibility. His high visibility appears to have given him a degree of protection. I would hesitate to write a book while anonymity was still an option. But if I got caught, a book would be ideal to make the case more visible.

Comment: @sav This case is not concerning nuclear weapons safety hazards.  It is about academe and the insane lengths a university went to cover up scientific/professional misconduct in reprisal of being called out.  That said, it could turn a field or two upside down in addition to multiple reputations being ruined.  Those in charge would also suffer greatly.

Comment: @M11293 I probably can't say. I suspect the whistleblower is the one in the best position to make that assessment as each case is different. The stakes in academia are not as serious as military matters, however it is best to be wary of making too many enemies.

Comment: What did you mean by "go public"?  If the problem is bad science, then contact the journals where the work was published.  If the problem is bad teaching, then contact the body that provides acreditation.  If the problem is something else, please be more specific.